TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hour') when replacing the sample data using MT5 Data
I was trying to use draggable trendline on top of CANDLESTICK series it's working okay until I replace the data from "https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlc.json" with a data from mt5.
I was thinking that it's because the mt5 data have saturday and sunday break. but I also think I was not providing the data with proper time interval? does Highstock charts require a specific timeframe? or is there any settings I can use to work with 5mins, 15minutes, 30minutes, 1hour, 1 day timeframe?
enter image description here
I did try to get 1 minute time frame but Its too many to load if I just want to view data with 1 hour timeframe

Highcharts Stock accepts the weekend breaks (or any other breaks) without any problem, due to the ordinal implementation. Therefore, your dataset only has to be sorted (in ascending order) and can contain breaks. The timeframe of the points is entirely up to you, and it can even be changed internally via data grouping.
However, make sure to use the correct data format require by candlestick series.
If you would like to use draggable-points module with Highcharts Stock, remember to disable dataGrouping for series that will be draggable. This module runs Point.update() underneath, which can only be used on non-grouped datasets.

I have tried it again still this "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chart')" error persist

Please reproduce your issue in a JSFiddle demo, with a static data so that I can have a look at it on my side. You can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s07Lxhtb/

https://jsfiddle.net/fcnavillangca/x4nf7z8j/24/
here I try to copy paste it

I checked my data it seems the date is not latest to oldest I will try to resort them

resorting it didn't make any difference

In Highcharts Stock, dataGrouping is enabled by default for each series - unfortunately, with dataGrouping we can't run Point.update method (which is used internally by draggable-points module). In order to use that functionality, you need to disable dataGrouping on the line series.
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kLqyhcf5/

Thanks for answering I'm gonna try that immediately and handle data grouping in server
